# My prefix has wild animals

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Can you find out a word that has these following rules:

-My prefix has alot of wild animals,

-My infix has a heavy demand,

-My suffix always questions themself,

-My whole has a word in the meaning that means a classification of something.

Answer (score 2):

Might this possibly clue the word:

> **ZOOLOGICAL**?

*My prefix has a lot of wild animals*

> A **ZOO** contains a *lot of animals* usually seen in the wild.

*My infix has a heavy demand*

> A **LOG** is produced by felling a tree. The [logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logging) industry is frankly vast, as there is *heavy demand* all around the world for products based on wood, including building materials, furniture and paper.

*My suffix always questions themself*

> Someone with a **[LOGICAL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logical)** mind is highly capable of reasoning, and is willing to question everything - even themselves - to find the right answer to a problem.

*My whole has a word in the meaning that means a classification of something.*

> **ZOO + LOG + LOGICAL** = The word **ZOOLOGICAL** relates to the study of the animal kingdom,  including the structure, embryology, evolution, **classification**, habits, and distribution of all animals, both living and extinct (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoology)).

Comment: I had a very similar solution with ZOOLOGY (logy being a slow person, may question themselves because they are slow), but I didn't feel that LOG was a close enough connection to heavy demand. Maybe it could be referring to something different?

Comment: @aguy I weighed that up myself before posting, and figured it could be justified in this way, and put down to what may well be just an unusual way of phrasing. In my experience, affix riddles (particularly those from users creating them for the first time) don't always have the especially *close* connection one might hope for - guess we'll just have to wait and see what the OP says! A valid remark though :)

Answer (score 0):

It could also be:

> oceanography

My prefix has a lot of wild animals:

> the ocean (mostly fish)

My infix has heavy demand:

> Graphs have heavy demand in many different fields of study

My suffix questions itself:

> Y? as in Why?

My whole has a word in the meaning that means a classification of something:

> Definition: the branch of science that deals with the physical and biological properties and phenomena of the sea. Properties is a word that is used to classify things.